# Android app does not start. Fails with a '...has stopped unexpectedly' message

Tags: android

Hello 
i am new in Android  i am trying to build a program but always when i wanted to start the program it gives me a message:"The application Traim Time (process timetrain.com )has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again." 
Ple Anyone can help me to solve problem
Thank you

this the code

```
package timetrain.com;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class timetrain extends Activity {

  private final static int REQUEST_TEXT=0;
  private EditText inputTime;
  private Button go1;
  int heure =0;



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 // Hide the title bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    go1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.go1);
    inputTime=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputTime);
    heure= Integer.parseInt (inputTime.getText().toString());

    go1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(v==go1){

                Intent intent = new Intent(timetrain.this,lirefile.class);
                intent.putExtra("enterTime",heure);

                startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_TEXT);
            }
        }

    });

}

public static int getRequestText() {
    return REQUEST_TEXT;
}
```

}

Comment: What does your logcat look like?

Comment: Without seeing any log to give us a clue what's going wrong - I'd guess that either `go1` or `inputTime` is coming back as a `null` value, and then when you go to do something with it, you get a null reference exception.

Comment: Also just to make sure...have you added the Activity to the manifest file?

Comment: I'll go with NumberFormatException :)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Just a few things incorrect ...

1. you have `startActivityForResult()`, but no corresponding `onActivityResult()` http://rahulonblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-startactivityforresult-example.html
2. `if(v==go1)`; == will not work the way you think with non primitives (ints/floats/booleans), and you need to use `v.equals(go1)` instead.

Comment: 2. is not exactly true. For Strings many get confused for `==` does not compare String contents. But in this case it's the instance which is expected to be compared. Can't say using equals did any harm either. Moreover the whole if-check is pretty much unnecessary as `v` shouldn't be nothing else than `go1`.

Comment: Actually 2 is exactly true ... if you are trying to compare object references then == is not what you need to use. In the case above, they are trying to compare View objects. Unless the objects share the same memory reference they will not be considered equal [http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html]

Comment: I'm not going to check if Button, or any class on it's inheritance path, overwrites `equals` from Object. But default implementation in [Object](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) uses `==` comparison. And wouldn't be surprised if in this case `v == go1` has the exact same effect as `v.equals(go1)`.